# Delphi: How to put the data from TStream into TStgMedium for OLE processing?

Tags: delphi, stream, delphi-2010, ole

I need to manage OLE drag-drop operations with Delphi. Now I got a problem - I need to put some data from TStream into global TStgMedium (to send it through OLE methods using IDataObject).

I guess there should be some commonly used pattern to do this? Can you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use [`TStreamAdapter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStreamAdapter) to adapt a `TStream` instance into an `IStream`.

The other approach that leaps out is to pass an `HGLOBAL` to `IDataObject.SetData` but that would be somewhat inefficient for large streams.

Comment: Ok, but how to store produced IStream into TStgMedium?

Comment: Assign it to `TStgMedium.stm` and set `TStgMedium.tymed` to `TYMED_ISTREAM`

Comment: Thanks! so simple. Can you also show the example of HGLOBAL method?

Comment: Use GlobalAlloc to get an HGLOBAL. Call GlobalLock to get a pointer. Then copy the entire stream into the memory behind that pointer. You can find all the details on MSDN.